# What are the cohomological dimensions of ${\rm Aut}(F_n)$, ${\rm Out}(F_n)$, ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ over the rationals ℚ and integers ℤ?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\Out{Out}\DeclareMathOperator{\cd}{cd}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$For a group $G$, the cohomological dimension of $G$ over the ring $R$, denoted by $\cd_R(G)$, is given by
$$\cd_R(G)=\max\{n : H^n(G;M)\neq 0 \hspace{1mm} \mbox{for some} \hspace{1mm}  RG\mbox{-module }M\}$$
However, $\Aut(F_n)$ is a discrete group of automorphisms of a free group with $n$ generators. The quotient by inner automorphisms is the outer automorphism group of a free group, denoted by $\Out(F_n)$. I would like to know the numbers $\cd_{\mathbb{Q}}\bigl(\Aut(F_n)\bigr)$,  $\cd_{\mathbb{Q}}\bigl(\Out(F_n)\bigr)$,  $\cd_{\mathbb{Q}}\bigl(\SL_n(\mathbb{Z})\bigr)$ and $\cd_{\mathbb{Z}}\bigl(\Aut(F_n)\bigr)$,  $\cd_{\mathbb{Z}}\bigl(\Out(F_n)\bigr)$,  $\cd_{\mathbb{Z}}\bigl(\SL_n(\mathbb{Z})\bigr)$.

P.S.  I have googled these numbers, but I mostly found ‘virtual cohomological numbers’.

Comment: If a group has non-trivial torsion it has infinite cohomological dimension over Z and so virtual cohomological dimension is a better way to go.

Comment: The groups you list always have torsion when $n\ge2$. The virtual cohomological dimension is defined to be the cohomological dimension of a torsion-free subgroup of finite index (if there is one), or $\infty$ (if not). One always has $$\mathrm{cd}_{\mathbb Q}(G)\le \mathrm{vcd}_{\mathbb Z}(G)\le\mathrm{cd}_{\mathbb Z}(G).$$ These facts may help you extract the information you need from the results about vcd that you have already found.

Comment: But for $\mathrm{cd}_\mathbf{Q}$ one also needs, in these cases, to know that it is at least equal to $\mathrm{vcd}_\mathbf{Z}$ (this is probably false in general?) and probably the way the lower bound for $\mathrm{vcd}_\mathbf{Z}$ is obtained also provides a lower bound for $\mathrm{cd}_\mathbf{Q}$. I'm not sure about Aut/Out($F_n$), but for $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$ this is indeed $n(n-1)/2$ (lower bound being given by the inclusion of the upper unipotent group).

Comment: It is not so easy to find groups of finite vcd for which $\mathrm{cd}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is not equal to $\mathrm{vcd}_{\mathbb{Z}}$: I don't know that this is the case for the groups asked about, but it would be surprising if it wasn't.

Comment: @IJL For mapping class groups, it seems $\textrm{cd}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ actually is less than $\textrm{vcd}_{\mathbb{Z}}$, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0622. By analogy I would guess then that it's also true for $Out(F_n)$, but I'm not finding this by googling, so maybe it's open.

Comment: @archipelago Ah, yes, I misread what cd_Q was. Actually, I guess the result of Harer they state in the first paragraph, using the Steinberg module, shows cd_Q = vcd_Z for mapping class groups.

Comment: @MattZaremsky: The easiest way to see they are equal is to note that the subgroups realizing the virtual cohomological dimension (the “Mess subgroups”) have nontrivial rational cohomology in their top degree.  In fact, I think you need these subgroups to prove Harer’s theorem.

Comment: @AndyPutman Ah, good point. So actually, right, thinking a little more about achieving bounds using subgroups, the easiest possible case is if vcd_Z=d and your group contains Z^d, then right away we get cd_Q=d. I guess it hadn't explicitly occurred to me that MCG(S_g) and SL_n(Z) don't satisfy this, but Out(F_n) and Aut(F_n) do satisfy this (it's easy to embed Z^{2n-2} into Aut(F_n)), so they're "easier" and I guess this answers the original question (I think).

Comment: @MattZaremsky: That’s right!  It’s curious that it’s so hard to find the correct lower bound on the cd for the mapping class groups, but trivial for automorphism groups of free groups and nearly trivial for SL(n,Z).

Comment: @AndyPutman That is pretty curious, maybe indicative of mapping class groups containing more "weird" subgroups than the others, or something. Well, I suppose I should officially answer the question now, once the kids give me time to actually think....

Comment: Name of @MattZaremsky's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437394/what-are-the-cohomological-dimensions-of-rm-autf-n-rm-outf-n#comment1127960_437394):  [Church, Farb, and Putman - The rational cohomology of the mapping class group vanishes in its virtual cohomological dimension](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0622).

Answer (score 11):

All the answers are contained in the comments by now, but let me compile everything together to be more official.

The easy part is that for all three groups, $\textrm{cd}_\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite, since the groups contain torsion.

As for $\textrm{cd}_\mathbb{Q}$, the answers are that $\textrm{cd}_\mathbb{Q}(\textrm{Aut}(F_n))=2n-2$, $\textrm{cd}_\mathbb{Q}(\textrm{Out}(F_n))=2n-3$, and $\textrm{cd}_\mathbb{Q}(\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}))=n(n-1)/2$.

Here are a few more details: In each case, this value equals the virtual cohomological dimension of the group. The vcd is always an upper bound, so the point is that for all these groups it is also a lower bound, which can be shown by exhibiting some subgroup whose $\textrm{cd}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is known to equal the vcd; call this a *witness* subgroup. For $\textrm{Aut}(F_n)$, it easy to see that it contains $\mathbb{Z}^{2n-2}$ as a witness (just consider all the automorphisms that fix $x_1$ and send each $x_i$ ($i\ne 1$) to $x_1^{m_i}x_i x_1^{n_i}$ for some $m_i,n_i\in\mathbb{Z}$). Similarly, for $\textrm{Out}(F_n)$ we have $\mathbb{Z}^{2n-3}$ as a witness. Finally, for $\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$, the subgroup of strictly upper triangular matrices is a witness.